# Shuffle Two NSMutableArray independently

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm creating two `NSMutableArray` in my `viewDidLoad`, I add it in a `NSMutableDictionary`. When I tried shuffling it with one array, It is okay. But the problem is when Im shuffling two arrays independently its not working,somehow the indexes got mixed up.

Here is my code for my array (1st Array):

```
self.items1 = [NSMutableArray new];

for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{ 

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Images%d.png", i]]; 
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        self.container = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [container setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath] forKey:@"items1"]; 
        [container setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index1"];
        [items1 addObject:container];           
    } 
} 

NSLog(@"Count : %d", [items1 count]);  

[items1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ images at index %d", object, index);
}];
```

(2nd Array):

```
self.items2 = [NSMutableArray new];  
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{ 

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"secondImages%d.png", i]]; 
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        self.container = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [container setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath] forKey:@"items2"]; 
        [container setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index2"];
        [items2 addObject:container];
    } 
} 

NSLog(@"Count : %d", [items2 count]);  

[items2 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ images at index %d", object, index);
}];
```

My view for the `iCarousel` where im using my array:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        NSDictionary *obj = [items1 objectAtIndex:index];
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[obj objectForKey:@"items1"]];
        view.tag = index;
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *obj = [items2 objectAtIndex:index];
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[obj objectForKey:@"items2"]];
        view.tag = index;
    }

    return view;
}
```

then my shuffle code(Which I tried duplicating for the other array,but not working also):

```
   srandom(time(NULL));
    NSUInteger count = [items1 count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
        [items1 exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
```

How am I going to shuffle it using above code (or if you have other suggestions) with two arrays? Thanks

My other problem is when I tries subclassing the class for the shuffle method or either use the above code, their index mixed. For example:

**Object**: apple, ball, carrots, dog

**Indexes**: 1       2      3      4

but in my View when shuffled:

**Object**: carrots, apple, dog, balle

**Indexes**: 2      4      1      3

I also have a method, that when the carousel stop, it will delete the image on view.

Comment: From the above code I see you are using only one array i.e item1 array. Where is the 2nd array you are using.

Comment: It is really not clear, what you mean by "shuffle two array". do u have to arrays and you want to shuffle both independently? or do you want to pick random elements from both and exchange them? create one shuffeld array from 2 arrays?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have to arrays and want to shuffle both independently.

Comment: @Anand i just posted one for short codes, but it same as the above but different images im getting.

Comment: repost, possible duplicate of [Shuffle/Random NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778945/shuffle-random-nsmutablearray)

Comment: By the way you're not really supposed to use `+[NSObject new]`. You should explicitly use alloc init pairs or convenience methods like `+[NSMutableArray array]`.

Comment: @JackLawrence okay, thank you. Ill try to change on that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the cleanest solution: use a [Objective-C Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html)

NSMutableArray+RandomUtils.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSMutableArray (RandomUtils) 
-(void)shuffle;
@end
```

NSMutableArray+RandomUtils.m

```
#import "NSMutableArray+RandomUtils.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (RandomUtils)
-(void)shuffle
{
    NSUInteger count = [self count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        NSUInteger nElements = count - i;
        NSUInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}

@end
```

import it, wherever you what to shuffle a MSMutableArray

```
[array1 shuffle];
[array2 shuffle];
```

---

I tried to reproduce your mixed indexes problem, but I can't

```
NSMutableArray *sarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@"carrots", @"apple", @"dog", @"balle"]];

NSLog(@"%@", sarray);
[sa enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ object at index %lu", obj, idx);
}];

[sarray shuffle];
 NSLog(@"%@", sarray);
[sarray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ object at index %lu", obj, idx);
}];
```

results in

```
(
    carrots,
    apple,
    dog,
    balle
)
carrots object at index 0
apple object at index 1
dog object at index 2
balle object at index 3
 (
    balle,
    dog,
    carrots,
    apple
)
balle object at index 0
dog object at index 1
carrots object at index 2
apple object at index 3
```

---

BTW: your example is aslo incorrect: with four objects in an array the indices should start with 0 and maximum is 3. you have 1 and 4.

so array is shuffled and indexes are ok. You must have some other problem in code, that you didn't show.

You should give up your real code.

---

I am still ot sure, if I understand, what you want. But from your comments I assume, you want to shuffle an array but keep the old indices. This is just not possible, as the index is the position of an object inside an array. But you are always free to save the original index somewhere.
Or you just copy an array, shuffle one of those. Now ho can ask for the index of an object in both arrays.

```
NSArray *originalArray =  @[@"carrots", @"apple", @"dog", @"balle"];

NSLog(@"%@", originalArray);
[originalArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ object at index %lu", obj, idx);
}];


NSArray *shuffledArray = [originalArray arrayShuffled];
 NSLog(@"%@", shuffledArray);
[shuffledArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ object at index %lu %lu", obj, idx, [originalArray indexOfObject:obj]);
}];
```

Comment: Have tried that, though indexes seem to be mixed too. Do you mind checkin my ViewController class?

Comment: what do you mean with indexes mixed? the index is always the number of the position of an object inside an array.

Comment: my app is `iCarousel` without shuffle. the Views work fine. but when i tried the shuffle method, indexes get mixed up.

Comment: I dont understand, what indexes get mixed up means. why do think, they are mixed up? How did you expect them to be? "mixed up" is not a problem description you can anybody expect to understand, what you mean. please alter your questions with these information.

Comment: my app is like a slot machine, so the user has the option to choose what they want to appear on the view when the slot machine is rolling, in my situation, when not shuffled, is fine. but when i used the shuffle method, the option for the user doesnt work. Indexes got mixed, in terms of Views.

Comment: I ask you, what does "get mixed" means, and you answer "it get mixed". Please add an example of this mix to your question. and not as a comment. otherwise only very few people will see it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your mixed up indices, see my answer.

Comment: Yes you got it, what i need is to just shuffle the views, but still retain their indexes, for example on what you are doing, tgat even when carrot is on the third position i still want it to be index 0, but how?

Comment: OK, you got it totally wrong: the index has to be changed for shuffling. you cannot just reorder it and then ask for the old order. shuffle is shuffle. of course you could store the old indices in a separate data structure.

Comment: I am not too sure what you want, but maybe my new code helps you.

Comment: i just want to randomize their order, not their indexes. Randomize their position in views. But still retain their original indexes.

Comment: I say it once again: you cannot change the order, without changing the index, as the indices are defined by the order. the index is the position inside the array. and a object doesnt retain it index. it doesnt know it index, as it isn't even aware, that it was sticked in one or more arrays.

Comment: as I said HOURS before: show us that code. your basic understanding of arrays is wrong.

Comment: So where is the famous second array? where are the views you are talking of? is it possible, that you are just trolling?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the idea is to shuffle two array in the same order then you just need to do the exchange of the 2nd array right after the 1st array?

```
NSUInteger count = [items1 count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    [items1 exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    [items2 exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

Comment: You tell us. You weren't clear at all on your requirement. If you need to shuffle two independent arrays with two different numbers of objects, then just repeat the loop a second time on the second array.

Comment: that's my problem then, when I try to put the same function its not working, but when I use it in one array in one of my `viewController` its working.

Comment: Then update your question with the code that is actually giving you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two different array of images which you need to shuffle the images.

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    {
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Images%d.png", i]]; 
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
//Lazy initialization of dictionary 
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dict setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath] forKey:@"items1"]; 
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index1"];
            [items1 addObject:dict]; 
    [dict release];          
        } 
    }
```

add the object to 2nd array in the same way.

```
NSUInteger count = [items1 count];
for(int i = 0 ;i < count; i++)
{
int nElements = count - i;
int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
[items1 exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

second array shuffling

```
 NSUInteger count = [items2 count];
    for(int i = 0 ;i < count; i++)
    {
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    [items2 exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
```

this should work. If you still find the problem let me know.

Comment: yes it your code I have just modified it.Are you still facing problem.

Comment: yes still having problem, cant shuffle right. indexes are mixing also.